# Neat inter-row calculations within pandas DataFrame with MultiIndex

Tags: python, pandas

I have the classic ucb admission dataset as a pandas DataFrame with multiIndex:

```
                            value
Dept      Gender  Admit     
A         Male    Admitted  512
                  Rejected  313
          Female  Admitted  89
                  Rejected  19
```

etc. for other departments ('A' through 'F')

and I want to create a table of the ratio of students accepted to rejected, grouped by Dept and Gender

My current approaches have been

```
ucbA.groupby(level=['Dept', 'Gender']).apply(lambda x: x.xs('Admitted', level=2).iloc[0] / x.xs('Rejected', level=2).iloc[0]).unstack().value
```

which is horrible

and

```
admitted = ucbA.unstack('Admit')
DataFrame({'Proportion Accepted': admitted.value.Admitted / admitted.value.Rejected}).unstack(1)
```

which ok I guess, but I feel it should be possible as a one-liner without unstacking.

Is there a really neat way of doing something like this? I'm imagining a one-liner staying within the context of the multi-index.

Edit: The full frame:

```
DataFrame({'Admit': {0: 'Admitted',  1: 'Rejected',  2: 'Admitted',  3: 'Rejected',  4: 'Admitted',  5: 'Rejected',  6: 'Admitted',  7: 'Rejected',  8: 'Admitted',  9: 'Rejected',  10: 'Admitted',  11: 'Rejected',  12: 'Admitted',  13: 'Rejected',  14: 'Admitted',  15: 'Rejected',  16: 'Admitted',  17: 'Rejected',  18: 'Admitted',  19: 'Rejected',  20: 'Admitted',  21: 'Rejected',  22: 'Admitted',  23: 'Rejected'}, 'Dept': {0: 'A',  1: 'A',  2: 'A',  3: 'A',  4: 'B',  5: 'B',  6: 'B',  7: 'B',  8: 'C',  9: 'C',  10: 'C',  11: 'C',  12: 'D',  13: 'D',  14: 'D',  15: 'D',  16: 'E',  17: 'E',  18: 'E',  19: 'E',  20: 'F',  21: 'F',  22: 'F',  23: 'F'}, 'Gender': {0: 'Male',  1: 'Male',  2: 'Female',  3: 'Female',  4: 'Male',  5: 'Male',  6: 'Female',  7: 'Female',  8: 'Male',  9: 'Male',  10: 'Female',  11: 'Female',  12: 'Male',  13: 'Male',  14: 'Female',  15: 'Female',  16: 'Male',  17: 'Male',  18: 'Female',  19: 'Female',  20: 'Male',  21: 'Male',  22: 'Female',  23: 'Female'}, 'value': {0: 512,  1: 313,  2: 89,  3: 19,  4: 353,  5: 207,  6: 17,  7: 8,  8: 120,  9: 205,  10: 202,  11: 391,  12: 138,  13: 279,  14: 131,  15: 244,  16: 53,  17: 138,  18: 94,  19: 299,  20: 22,  21: 351,  22: 24,  23: 317}}).set_index(['Dept', 'Gender', 'Admit']).astype(float).astype(int)
```

Alternatively if you have rpy:

```
import pandas.rpy.common as com
ucbA = com.load_data('UCBAdmissions').set_index(['Dept', 'Gender', 'Admit']).astype(float).astype(int)
```

Comment: It looks like you are calculating the ratio of accepted to rejected, not the proportion of students who are accepted. Is that right? Also, if you could provide a small snippet of code that actually creates this data frame with at least two levels of the Dept index, that would help tremendously.

Answer (score 4):

Here you go:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Dept':['A','A','A','A'],
                   'Gender':['Male', 'Male', 'Female', 'Female'],
                   'Admit':['Admitted', 'Rejected', 'Admitted', 'Rejected'],
                   'value':[512,313,89,19]})
df = df.set_index(['Dept', 'Gender', 'Admit'])


# Proportions accepted and rejected:
df / df.groupby(level=['Dept','Gender']).transform(sum)
#                         value
#Dept Gender Admit             
#A    Female Admitted  0.824074
#            Rejected  0.175926
#     Male   Admitted  0.620606
#            Rejected  0.379394

# If you really want admitted as fraction of rejected:
df2 = df.swaplevel(1,2).swaplevel(0,1)
df2.ix['Admitted'] / df2.ix['Rejected']
#                value
#Dept Gender          
#A    Male    1.635783
#     Female  4.684211
```

Comment: Great answer. Preserving "one-liner-ness" in this case is a bad idea. Code is read more often than written, and so reading something clear is better than something hard to penetrate that achieves one line by verbose abuse of a fluent interface. This also highlights some downfalls of [fluent interfaces](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/FluentInterface.html), e.g. you get a handful of mega classes that are overburdened to make things expressive. In this case, MultiIndex, DataFrame, and GroupBy are far too overburdened to make everything fluent, things become less expressive.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way

```
In [55]: grouper = ['Dept','Gender']

In [56]: x = df.reset_index()

In [57]: (x[x.Admit=='Admitted'].groupby(grouper).sum() / 
          x[x.Admit=='Rejected'].groupby(grouper).sum()
         ).unstack()
Out[57]: 
           value          
Gender    Female      Male
Dept                      
A       4.684211  1.635783
B       2.125000  1.705314
C       0.516624  0.585366
D       0.536885  0.494624
E       0.314381  0.384058
F       0.075710  0.062678

[6 rows x 2 columns]
```